# PHP namespaces issue with sub-folders

Tags: php

I have very simple web app. Learning how to use namespaces.

Structure of directories is:

- www (root)

  - class (application directory)

    - index.php
    - payment (sub-directory for namespace)

      - card.php (separate class, namespace)
    - gameplay (sub-directory for namespace)

      - card.php (separate class,
        namespace)

Code is as follows:

index.php

```
<?php 
    function my_autoload_function($c)
    {
        require_once "class/".str_replace("\\","/",$c).".php";      
    }

    spl_autoload_register('my_autoload_function');

    $gpcard=new \gameplay\card;
    $gpcard->play();
?>
```

card.php (subfolder payment)

```
<?php 
    namespace payment;
    class Card
    {
        public function pay()
        {
            echo "Pay to play";
        }
    }
?>
```

card.php (subfolder gameplay)

```
<?php 
    namespace gameplay;
    class Card
    {
        public function play()
        {
            echo "Play game";
        }
    }
?>
```

Error messages which I get are:

> Warning: require_once(class/gameplay/card.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\class\index.php on line 4
>   Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'class/gameplay/card.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\class\index.php on line 4

Although all files and subfolders (namespaces) exists, something is wrong.

Can anybody help?

Comment: One thing I would be careful of is being consistent with the case of the names/file names.  Windows is OK, but *nix IS case sensitive for file names.  So make sure you always use Card for class and file names.

Comment: I made two corrections based on your suggestions, but still doesn't work. This is Windows 10 anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This index.php file will work, if it'd be moved one directory level higher.
It should be in /www directory, not in /class, because it adds the 'class' in the path.
If you need it under /class you need

```
require_once str_replace("\\","/",$c).".php";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see how it works on small framework here:
https://github.com/breakermind/Tronix/blob/master/router.php
and autoload here:
https://github.com/breakermind/Tronix/blob/master/classes/autoload.php

classes/Folder1/Folder2/ClassName.php

```
// index.php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classes/autoload.php');
use Folder1\Folder2\ClassName;

ClassName cl = new ClassName();



// Class file path classes\Folder1\Folder2\ClassName.php  
namespace Folder1\Folder2;

class ClassName{
    // Do something...methods...variables ...
}
```

Something like this